# Trigger an event on single markers in leaflet LayerGroup

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

Hi everyone (or should I say "anyone [who would read this...]?) :)

I have tried to find the answer for two days but without success (most likely because I am a brand new user). I have on a leaflet map markers organized in a Layergroup so I can manage them with Layercontrol. I would like that when a marker is clicked it triggers an event (in my case the creation of a circle representing a specific distance around this marker). I would like to manage that outside of the individual markers because I want also to set some different options for the radius of the circle according to the distance selected by the user.

Below are different pieces of code showing what I mean :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head> 
<title>Example</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<style>

body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin:0;
}

#map{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var sites = [
        {'loc':[42.2793869135936,9.53257201027757],'title':'TORRA A I CASELLI'},
        {'loc':[42.2713622720985,9.50678498185463],'title':'TOUR GIANDINELLI'},
        {'loc':[42.641518105666,9.00587322013212],'title':'TOUR DE LOSARI'},];

var map = new L.Map('map');
map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));
map.setView([42.5,9.2210706018535],9);

var marks = new L.LayerGroup();
    for(i in sites) {
        var title = sites[i].title,
            loc = sites[i].loc,
            markersites = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title});
        markersites.bindPopup('<strong>'+title+'</strong><br>');
        marks.addLayer(markersites);
    }
marks.addTo(map);

// for now it is all good, the next part is where I fail

marks.on('click',function(){
    console.log("Yeah!");
    new L.circle(this.getLatLng(), 10000, {color:'red', fillOpacity:0.3}).addTo(map)});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for your attention.

Cheers,
Guillaume.

Comment: Please me know if my answer does not work for you. I upvoted your question because you provided a working leaflet example, very easy to open and experiment with!

Comment: I'm glad you say that! I was hesitating in my posting considering that maybe my question is looking too big, and my piece of code too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you are using a LayerGroup is not part of your problem.

First, you have to attach a 'click' listener on all your markers. This way, you can draw your circle when the popup is opened. You also must keep a reference to this circle in the javascript popup object.

```
// keep a reference on the current active circle
var activeCircle = false;

markersites.on('click', function(e) {
   // marker clicked is e.target

   // remove active circle if any
   if(activeCircle) {
     map.removeLayer(activeCircle);
   }
   // draw a 10km circle with the same center as the marker 
   activeCircle = L.circle(e.target.getLatLng(), { radius: 10000 , color: "#ff0000" }).addTo(map);
       });
```

Example is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OufPbq07ywEZh1N5VA8Y?p=preview

Comment: Ok, indeed it works thanks! However I would like to keep the circle as long as I didn't click on another marker (even if I close the popup). This is because I plan to manage the layer with these circles through the control.layer panel. I'm currently looking into making this happen, but if you have some additionnal information it is very welcome.

Comment: In this case you just need to keep a reference on the last circle you created. See the updated answer and example. You are welcome to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have one last question that remains : I would like to manage these circles as a separate layer, then it seems to me needed to create them outside of the function defining the markers. Would you know how to do that? Thank you again for the answers you already gave me.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure I understand. You should start a new topic with an example or a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are binding popups to your markers, a leaflet popup is going to open up in response to click events. However, you can hook into those events by adding your own callbacks, too like:

```
map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
 currentPopup = e.popup; // keep track of current popup
 // Do stuff with the popup or inspect it's marker here...
});
```

There are probably other ways to solve this with the leaflet api which is very flexible. This approach has worked for me in the past.

Also at the time you are creating popups, you can bind additional info if necessary like this:

```
var content = '<b>'+ something + '</b>: '+ etc;
var popup = L.popup();
popup.setContent(content);
popup.markerId = 'some id';
layer.bindPopup(popup);
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks! But the answer of FranceImage below fit better to my need since it applies directly on the LayerGroup, even if I still remain looking for a way to remove these circles independently from the popupclose event.

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to upvote my answer, which is the best way to say 'thanks' on SO.